# In JavaScript, why can any value be spread in an object, but not in an array?

Tags: javascript, iterator, iterable, spread-syntax

Spreading any "empty" value in an object is valid (does not throw an error but instead becomes a kind of no-op):

```
{
  ...undefined,
  ...null,
  ...false,
  ...true,
  ...'',
  ...{},
  ...[],
  ...Symbol(),
  ...() => {},
} // evaluates to {}
```

But doing the same in an array throws an error for all the above values except `''` and `[]`. The error message says that the values that don't work are not iterable, however, they clearly *are* iterable in the sense that they can be spread into an object. Granted, it intuitively makes sense that strings, arrays, and objects can be converted to entries/key-value pairs when being spread into an object and converted to values when spread into an array, but even so, why would the entries of all those values be iterable but the values not be? If the entries are iterable, shouldn't the values be as well? Is this just a quirk of different JavaScript engines?  What's going on here?

Comment: The rules for spread operator for arrays and object literals are different. When used with object literals, there is no requirement that the spread operator be applied to iterables: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [object literals the `spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) **copies own [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) from a provided object onto a new object**. So in your examples none of the provided "entities" to the spread operator have any enumerable properties.

With arrays the spread syntax is only applied to [iterable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables).

Or objects which implement the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) ... meaning:

> The object (or one of the objects up its prototype chain) must have a
>   property with a @@iterator key which is available via constant
>   [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

Core objects which do that are:

- [Array.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)
- [TypedArray.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/@@iterator)
- [String.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator)
- [Map.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator)
- [Set.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator)

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you :-) Knowing that using the spread operator within an object literal copies the operand's enumerable properties whereas using it in an array literal simply attempts to call the operand's iterator makes the behavior of the examples I gave make perfect sense.